# Are fund manager names listed in Edgar filings?

Tags: united-states, mutual-funds, edgar

Does anyone know if the fund manager names are listed in any Edgar filings and if so which form type they are listed in?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The company which manages the fund's portfolio is normally given in the fund's prospectus, and often the lead person within that company is also listed by name.  The prospectus is available anywhere you can get shares (e.g. the fund's website), and is also available at sec.gov's [EDGAR](http://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/companysearch.html).  The filing type for fund prospectuses is 485, but often there's a button labeled "Prospectuses" for easier access.